I'm getting on gitbash a warning WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! for github
When I try to clone a git repository in gitbash on Windows I get following error:
$ ssh -T git@github.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:secretkeysCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /c/Users/asterios/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /c/Users/asterios/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.


https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

The solution was to remove the existing entry from github in the known_hosts file and run the same command on gitbash. Then comes the question if you want to add the fingerprint from github. Answer with yes and this will insert the new entry from github in the known_hosts file
